# Multiple Search Criteria Single Field in T-SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have an issue where I need to pass multiple criteria for a single field in SQL.  For example if I was looking for all book titles which contained Ruby, PHP, or ASP.Net.  Also, I only want to return a limited number of rows for pagination.  I know I could do dynamic sql, but I am sure there is probably a better way.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your searchwords in a table it is not so hard.

```
declare @criteria table(text1 varchar(20)) 
declare @searchtable table(longertext varchar(2000)) 

--lines wanted  
declare @linefrom int
declare @lineto int 

set @linefrom = 1
set @lineto = 2

insert @criteria values('asp.') 
insert @criteria values('ruby') 

insert @searchtable values('bla bla ruby') 
insert @searchtable values('bla asp. bla') 
insert @searchtable values('ruby asp. bla') 

;with a as ( 
select s.longertext, rn = row_number() over(order by longertext) from @searchtable s join @criteria c 
on s.longertext like '%'+ c.text1+'%' 
group by s.longertext 
) 
select longertext from a 
where rn between @linefrom and @lineto
```

Result:

```
bla asp. bla
bla bla ruby
```

Comment: Could I not use a view with the results I want and join the criteria table to that or would it be much slower?

Comment: @Wade73 You can't make a view that includes the results. Not unless you know all the criterias before creating the view, and that would defeat the purpose of this assignment.

Comment: Well all the search table has is the field I want to search, why could I not search the same field in a view (or table), rather than inserting it into a temp table?

Comment: @Wade73 that would be possible. I thought you meant you wanted the search i wrote and the view you mentioned included in the same view, that would not be possible.